# limit output from a sort method

Tags: python, django, python-itertools

if my views code is:

```
arttags = sorted(arttags, key=operator.attrgetter('date_added'), reverse=True)
```

what is the argument that will limit the result to 50 tags?

I'm assuming this:

```
.... limit=50)
```

is incorrect.

more complete code follows:

```
videoarttags = Media.objects.order_by('date_added'),filter(topic__exact='art') 
audioarttags = Audio.objects.order_by('date_added'),filter(topic__exact='art') 
conarttags = Concert.objects.order_by('date_added'),filter(topic__exact='art') 
arttags = list(chain(videoarttags, audioarttags, conarttags)) 
arttags = sorted(arttags, key=operator.attrgetter('date_added'), reverse=True)
```

how do incorporate –

```
itertools.islice(sorted(...),50)
```

Comment: sorted() is not an itertools filter -- it returns a plain list rather than an iterator

Comment: my mistake. in the previous line of code I use itertools to chain a bunch of tags into "arttags". I mistakenly thought I was using an itertools sort filter as well.

Comment: @kjarsenal, it's impossible to sort in a stream-oriented way: you can't yield even the first resulting item until you've seen all incoming ones (as the last one you see might be the first one to yield!), and itertools only does stream-oriented things of course.

Comment: the sort filter works. i just need to know how to limit the result.

Answer (score 4):

what about [heapq.nlargest](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest):
Return a list with the n largest elements from the dataset defined by iterable.key, if provided, specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each element in the iterable: `key=str.lower Equivalent to: sorted(iterable, key=key, reverse=True)[:n]`

```
>>> from heapq import nlargest
>>> data = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0]
>>> nlargest(3, data)
[9, 8, 7]
```

Comment: This is probably the fastest way of getting only the first few sorted elements.  That's exactly what I would have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably find that a slice works for you:

```
arttags = sorted(arttags, key=operator.attrgetter('date_added'), reverse=True)[:50]
```

Comment: yeah, I thought so too, but it had no effect.

Comment: In what way did this not work? You mention itertools, if you want an iterator, try `itertools.islice(sorted(...),50)`

Comment: the code looks like this:

videoarttags = Media.objects.order_by('date_added'),filter(topic__exact='art')
audioarttags = Audio.objects.order_by('date_added'),filter(topic__exact='art')
conarttags = Concert.objects.order_by('date_added'),filter(topic__exact='art')
arttags = list(chain(videoarttags, audioarttags, conarttags))
arttags = sorted(arttags, key=operator.attrgetter('date_added'), reverse=True)

how do incorporate – itertools.islice(sorted(...),50)

Comment: @kjarsenal, pls edit your question to put this code there (it's unreadable all flowed in a comment) and to fix the question's title (as itertools has nothing to do with sorted).

Answer (score 0):

The general idea of what you want is a `take`, I believe.  From [the itertools documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
def take(n, iterable):
    "Return first n items of the iterable as a list"
    return list(islice(iterable, n))
```

Comment: can't figure out how to implement it in the django view using the module.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was pretty much barking up the wrong tree. What I was trying to accomplish was actually very simple using a template filter (slice) which I didn't know I could do.
The code was as follows:

```
{% for arttag in arttags|slice:":50" %}
```

Yes, I feel pretty stupid, but I'm glad I got it done :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to add [:50] to each of the `objects.order_by.filter` calls.  Doing that will mean you only ever have to sort 150 items in-memory in Python instead of possibly many more.